# How can I figure out color hex codes from a screen capture?

Tags: colors, screen-capture

I have a screen capture of some colors I'd like to use. I need to learn their hex codes. I have the screen shot in MS paint. I can see where I can pull the color with the dropper, and where I can define custom colors, but I don't see any place where it tells me the hex code of the color.

Can I do this in mspaint, or gimp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you select color with Dropper, go to Tools->Edit colors and click on Define Custom Colors. On right side you will get three numbers (Red, Green and Blue). Convert those numbers to their hexadecimal form (Windows Calculator will do) and just have them one after another (Red, Green and then blue).

This is as far as I know only way to do it in MS Paint. However, You might think of [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) or better editor as alternate solution since almost all other image editors do have that feature available.

Answer (score 3):

It's trivial in GIMP. Just use the color picker tool, then click on the color box and look at `HTML notation`. Heck, you don't even have to open the image; the color box can grab the color from any pixel on your screen.